# Specifying Z offset in Marlin firmware

Tags: marlin, calibration, firmware, z-probe

I need to set a Z offset for the Flying bear P902. I calculated the offset (-2.98). But, every time when I try to input this using the LCD screen of my 3D printer, the value jumps to either -2.99 or -2.97. As -2.97 is just a little bit too far from the bed and -2.99 is just a little bit too close to the bed (and -2.98 is perfect), I really want to input this specific value. I have tried many times on the LCD screen and also in the firmware itself.

But, even after uploading the firmware, it still displays -2.97.

This is the line of code I was changing:

```
#define Z_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER -2.98 // Z offset: -below +above  [the nozzle]
```

Is there a way I can input -2.98?

Comment: I really doubt that 1/100 of a mm would make that effect on adhesion, the deviation of the positioning accuracy is most probable even higher than that!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Z-offset persitently stored in memory?

Maybe the value of `-2.97` for the `Z_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER`  is retained in the EEPROM memory when you upload new firmware.

You could try to send the G-code [`M502`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M502:_Read_parameters_from_.22configuration.h.22) to the machine to re-load the values from the firmware overwriting currently stored values.

#### Alternative Z-offset using G-code commands

Note that there is a different (and more common) solution to set the Z-offset using G-code [`M851`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M851:_Set_Z-Probe_Offset), you can do this after you uploaded the firmware to the printer. Sending G-code commands can be done using printer software and a USB connection to the printer through a so-called **terminal** interface. This can be done in OctoPrint, Repetier-Host, Pronterface (Printrun software suite), and probably many more. Alternatively, you could make seperate G-code (basically text files with extension `.g`) files with each step in a single file and "print" the files through the SD interface of the printer menu.

The following strategy must be followed to specify the Z offset:

- Heat your printer up to your printing temperature and allow a few minutes for it to expand and settle
- Reset the existing Z-offset to zero `M851 Z0`
- Home all axes `G28`
- Move the nozzle to the middle of the bed `G1 X110 Y110` (if your bed is 220 x 220)
- Turn off the software endstops with `M211 S0`
- Move the nozzle down so it is just gripping a piece of standard printer paper
- Set the Z-offset to the displayed value. E.g. if the printer displays a Z-Value of `-1.23` enter `M851 Z-1.23`
- Store it to the EEPROM `M500`
- **Important notice!** Enable the endstops again with `M211 S1` or the printer head will collide with the bed on the next `G28` command

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped. I used Repetier-Host and was able to calculate the new z offset and store it. After that, I printed something and it was successful!